CoreWCF: Anomalous "AWAIT_TIME" of 23 Seconds during the execution of an inner method
we are reporting several cases where 99% of the duration of requests handled by our web app C# .net 6.0 are for CoreWCF libraries. Requests with anomalous response times represent a percentage of around 1% of the total amount of requests. However, since it is a performance critical app (with transactions and payments), 1% of anomalous responses is still too high.
Please look at the following 2 screen-shots that can further clarify the issue.
<<Screenshot 1>> In the "End-to-end transaction" section of the Azure portal you can see the "Duration" column clearly showing that - most of the execution time of the request - does not concern the code executing in the WebMethod of the APIs, but rather code executed upstream (almost 23 seconds taken upstream of the WebMethod vs a few tens of milliseconds regarding the execution time of the code in the WebMethod's scope).
<<Screenshot 2>> The second screenshot shows the code stack upstream of the request management by our custom WebMethod. Here, in most cases, the libraries involved are related to CoreWCF.
It is also interesting to note the "AWAIT_TIME" of 22,458 ms affecting the ConcurrencyBehavior.LockInstanceAsync method of CoreWCF.primitives.


Here is the implementation code of CoreWCF in the Program.cs file of our app.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Net;

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("mySettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });

    var mySettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").Get<MySettings>();

    // Add WSDL support
    builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices();
    builder.Services.AddServiceModelMetadata();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceBehavior, UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior>();

    var factory = (IServiceProvider provider) =>
    {        
        var connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStringName");
        var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TransApiContext>()
                                .UseSqlServer(connString)
                                .Options;
        var clientFactory = new ClientFactory(mySettings.HttpCallsRetryAttempts, mySettings.PooledConnectionLifetimeInMinutes);
        return new MyWcfService(mySettings, contextOptions, clientFactory);
    };

    builder.Services.AddTransient(factory); // Init SoapApi

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    }

    // Setup options service
    builder.Services.AddOptions();
    // Load options from section "AuthOptionsSection"
    builder.Services.Configure<AuthOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AuthOptionsSection"));

    var sBasicAuth = "BasicAuthentication";
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(sBasicAuth).AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>(sBasicAuth, null);

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        // Only check for basic auth when path is for the TransportWithMessageCredential endpoint only
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/myAppName/myWcfService"))
        {
            if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                // Check if currently authenticated
                var authResult = await context.AuthenticateAsync(sBasicAuth);
                if (authResult.None || !authResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    // If the client hasn't authenticated, send a challenge to the client and complete request
                    await context.ChallengeAsync(sBasicAuth);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
        // Either the request was authenticated of it's for a path which doesn't require basic auth
        await next(context);
    });
    
    app.UseServiceModel(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddService<MyWcfService>(serviceOptions =>
        {
            serviceOptions.DebugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
            serviceOptions.BaseAddresses.Add(new Uri("http://localhost/myAppName"));
            serviceOptions.BaseAddresses.Add(new Uri("https://localhost/myAppName"));
            serviceOptions.DebugBehavior.HttpsHelpPageEnabled = true;
            serviceOptions.DebugBehavior.HttpsHelpPageUrl = new Uri("https://localhost/myAppName/help");
            serviceOptions.DebugBehavior.HttpHelpPageUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/myAppName/help");
        })
        .AddServiceEndpoint<MyWcfService, IMyWcfServiceV6>(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), "/myWcfService");
        var serviceMetadataBehavior = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
    }); 
    

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    await app.RunAsync();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ConsoleError(ex);
}

static void ConsoleError(Exception ex)
{
    var msg = "Unexpected error during the initialization of myAppName App! {0} - {1}";
    string errMsg1 = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message;
    string errMsg2 = ex.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(msg, errMsg1, errMsg2);
}


Has anyone by chance come across the same issue before? If someone could help us we would be very grateful!
Thanks in advance.
E.
